# How to pass a param to linq query that would match both all items and items with null value?

Tags: c#, linq

I am trying to write a linq query that will return all items if parameter is null and return a matching item if parameter is not null.

For example

```
public void Search(int? assigneeId)
{
var results = _dbSet.Where(a=> assigneeId == null || a.AssigneeId == assigneeId)
}
```

If I want to retrieve all results, param assigeeId should be null, if I want to match item by assigeeId, param should have a value. But what if I want to match items that have null for assigneeId? How can I do that since null param cannot match both all items and ones without a value.

Comment: you need a additional parameter to controll that `public void Search(int? assigneeId, bool showallvalues)`

Comment: So, when the `assigneeId` is null then you want to return all items in `_dbSet` and when `assigneeId` is not null then you want to return just the records matching `a.AssigneeId == assigneeId`. So, if the function prototype is `public IEnumerable<RecordType> Search(int? assigneeId)` then why can't you do `if (assigneeId.HasValue) { result = <non-null query>; } else { result = <null query>; }`?

Comment: @Daniel Dearlove if param assigneeId is null, i also want to return items where a. AsigneeId == null

Comment: @fubo i was thinking to add additional param, but it looked as a poor solution. I was thinking of assigning a value - 1 as match all, null as match null items and any int as to match exact value.

Comment: @mko, so the where clause when you have an assignee ID is `a.AssigneeId == assigneeId.Value || a.AssigneeId == null`? Am I missing something?

Comment: Sounds like `a.AssigneeId` is of type `int?` in which case all values of `assigneeId` could be valid. It is poor programming to conflate two different meanings into one parameter with special values. Adding a second parameter `returnAllItems` is the correct approach (I would make it the first parameter: `public void Search(bool returnAllItems, int? asssigneeId)` - but in that case why not just have a second method, `ReturnAllItems()` and the original method `Search(int? assigneeId)`?

Comment: @NetMage i assume that using returnAllItems=true would exclude filtering items by assigneeId. Furthermore, lets aasume you have a complex url query such as tickets?assigneeId=&status=1, what would be a common interpretation of assigneId=null? Show all, or show only unassigned tickets? Adding showallassigneeids sounds like an overkill. Woudnt assigneeId=-1 be a good approach to show all?

Comment: I don't think there is a common or preferred interpretation, but at that point I would suggest `tickets?assigneeId=Any&status=1` taking advantage of the string parameter.

Answer (score 1):

Your dbSet is an IQueryable of items that have a property `assigneeId`.

If the parameter `int? assigneeId` has a value, you want to query all items in dbSet that have either a null value for property assigneeId, or a value that equals the int parameter.

If the parameter does not have a value you want all items in the dbSet.

How about this:

```
public void Search(int? assigneeId)
{
    var results = assigneeId.HasValue ?
        _dbSet.Where(a=> assigneeId == null || a.AssigneeId == assigneeId.Value) :
        _dbSet;
```

Of if you want, and you know that dbSet is an `IQueryable<MyClass>`, you could do the following which is in essence the same:

```
IQueryable<MyClass> results;
if (assigneeId.HasValue)
{
    results = _dbSet.Where(a=> assigneeId == null || a.AssigneeId == assigneeId.Value);
}
else
{
    results = dbSet;
}
// etc.
```

If you need to do this more often, for several other `IQueryable<T>` you want to fetch either all items, or only the items that match a certain value or have a null value, consider to create an extension method:

```
static class MyExtensions
{
    public static IQueryable<TSource> WhereEqualsValueOrAll<TSource, TProperty>(
        this IQueryable<TSource> source,
        Expression<Func<TSource, TProperty> propertySelector,
        TProperty? propertyValue)
    {
        if (propertyValue.HasValue)
        {
            return source.Where(
               propertySelector(source) == null)
               || propertySelector(source) == propertyValue.Value);
        }
        else
            return source;
}
```

Usage: suppose DbSet implements `IQueryable<Task>`, every Task is either not assigned to anyone, or to an Employee. Property AssigneeId is the foreign key to this Employee, or null if not assigned

```
Employee john = ...
IQueryable<Task> TasksUnassignedOrAssignedToJohn = dbSet.WhereEqualsValueOrAll(
    task => task.AssigneeId,
    john.Id);
```

In words: from the sequence of `Tasks` in `dbSet`, return only those tasks, that have a null value for property task.AssigneeId, or a value that equals john.Id. The effect is that you get all Tasks that are either unassigned (null value), or that are assigned to john.

Comment: thanks for this answer, but _dbSet.Where(a=> assigneeId == null || a.AssigneeId == assigneeId.Value) : would return either all is assigneeId == null or would match assigneeId to a.AssigneeId if parameter is provided. But would if I want to match  items with a.AssigneeId == null? That is my main concern here.